# reverting my git remote master branch to a specifc commit

Tags: git

I've been researching this for most of the last 2 days and trying various things i found and keep running into issues with every approach i try.

We inadvertently pushed some changes intended for a future release into master and now want to revert to the commit that matches our current release.

We have to deliver code to master via a pull-request.

I've tried various approaches that are able to reset HEAD on my local machine to the version I want but I can't then create a pull request that will merge to master (or a copy for testing purposes).

I tried reverting all the commits since the last good version but i get merge conflicts.  This i really don't understand as surely going backwards along the timeline the previous file version would be known.

No one in our team develops against master and everyone would be happy to have master back to the correct version so there are no history issues resetting back to the correct commit.

Is there an easy way to do this?  The hacky way that i am considering is: copy all files from the commit we want, checkout a master_merge branch, delete all the files, copy in the files from the good commit, create pull request.  Somehow this seems like it isn't a good idea but I've lost a day and a half trying to sort this out and that seems like it would get the job done.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Russ

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer to you question is much more about your process and what do you want to achieve.

- You leave the master at it is and create a tag for the commit you want and then you pull from there in case you wanna deploy that version.
- You can cherry pick a commit from one branch into another. This will actually do what you mentioned in your question, but you will keep any other extra code you already have.
- You can reverse your commit.
- You can diff the two codes, remove the extra one and then commit as you want. This if you don't mind loosing the code which has been written since the version you are rollbacking to.

Don't feel like the solution you picking is good or not, think if it it will give you the output your need, will be done securely, on a reasonable time and would let you keep the flow afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to git push force a previous ID for a given branch.

Say you want to "revert" master on remote origin to what it had without the last two commits.

Get the sha1 of the revision you would like it to be on (with git log, for example), then force-push it

`git push origin -f whatever-sha1-id:master`

That will set remote master to what it had without the last 2 commits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This works really well if i run it against a copy of master.  It fails the "commit without pull request" check when I try to run it against master.

It also shows all the diffs between the "fixed" branch and master as being in master (which makes sense as it's an older branch) but this means I can't create a pull request to deliver the reverted branch to master.

Comment: If you are asking for a mandatory pull request, that's not going to hold water because you are moving the "old" master branch forward with a merge of the possible pull request with the fixed master... in other words, your old "broken" master that you want to hack is not going out.